# How to enable “supportsAppend” in ArcGIS Online REST API

Tags: arcgis-online, arcgis-rest-api, append

I am looking for some help using AGOL and the REST API.

We have a project where users are making new routes for a network. We need to be able to upload and append their GPX data to an AGOL feature layer (they will not be updating existing features). Because AGOL doesn't accept GPX we convert the GPX to a GeoJson file on the website server and then send this to the AGOL environment however we get an error **'Append not enabled'** (sync and track changes are turned off), so how do we enable this?

I can do this exact process using AGOL so why does it fail using the REST API?

I have made sure that the field format is correct for the new GeoJson file by exporting the structure from the existing feature service and because we can do this process manually.

All help very welcome, we have been stuck on this for **weeks** and its key to the project.

Answer (score 0):

Try to enable editing on the hosted feature layer. It's a checkbox on the feature layer's ArcGIS Online "settings" tab.

Comment: Thank you, yes we have tried that but it does not automatically enableAppend

Comment: Darn, sorry this was not able to help.